# Installing the newest scipy (0.9) in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy

I tried following the [tutorial](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux) but after hours of building the ATLAS + LAPACK I got an error in the make install. I tried to download the following 4 libraries and install it still but no dice.

Currently I have installed numpy 1.3 and scipy 0.7.2 from the ubuntu repositories. I need a feature from scipy 0.9 though. Any way (preferably foolproof) I could install it?

Comment: The ones after ATLAS and LAPACK in the tutorial. (UMFPACK, AMD, UFConfig and CHOLMOD). Well, I guess the correct term would've been dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

ActivePython includes a package manager that allows you to install scipy 0.9 (among numpy, matplotlib, etc.) from [PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/scipy/).

```
pypm install numpy
```

These packages are built with ATLAS + LAPACK (Linux), veclib (OSX) or Intel MKL / ifortran (Windows).

Answer (score 1):

To install Scipy 0.9, you need to have a newer Numpy installed than 1.3. The oldest Numpy that it will work with is 1.4:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance%2F0.9.x/INSTALL.txt

Hopefully upgrading your Numpy install will help!

Otherwise, I second Josh's recommendation for prepackaged distributions. I know several people who use [Sage](http://sagemath.org) and say it is very easy to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) to get most of my scientific libraries packaged cleanly in one place:

http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php

It's free if you're in academia.

There are also other options like Python(x,y) and Sage:

http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

http://sagemath.org/

Prepackaged distributions are the closest you'll get to a foolproof way. I have built scipy/numpy from scratch before, but I can't help you without further details.

Answer (score 0):

Where you able to install the dependencies first?

```
sudo apt-get install gcc g77 python-dev atlas3-base-dev
```

And then proceed with the installation of scipy?

Comment: Okay, but you don't do a make install after that. you do `python setup.py build` and that is it. Your scipy is built in the build directory and then you can install it using `python setup.py install` if you want to install. Make sure you use the system python.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 11.10, I needed the following: `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran`, then `sudo pip install scipy`.

Comment: @Jabba This should be an answer. Worked great for me.